# Vue.js: How to get the offsetX from the "currentTarget" when mouse moving over its child elements?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

For instant:

```
<div class="synonym-list-wrapper" @mousemove="onMouseMove($event)">
        <ul class="synonym-list" ref="synonymList" :style="{transform:'translateX(' + translateX + 'px)'}">
            <li v-for="s of synonyms" :key="s._id">
                <section class="synonym">
                </section>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

methods: {

    onMouseMove(e) {

        console.log(e.target, e.offsetX);
    }
}

.synonym-list-wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I wanna that when the mouse move over the "div.synonym-list-wrapper", I always get the event always comes from the element "div.synonym-list-wrapper", not its child, neither "ul", "li" or "section".

Because I wanna make a carousel, which means I need to get the offsetX value from the event, and base on this value, apply translateX value to "ul.synonym-list".

So how can I achieve my goal, anyone has an idea, please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define `translateX` in `data` object:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      translateX: Number
    }
}
```

And in `onMouseMove` method set `translateX` value equal to `event.offsetX` value:

```
methods: {
    onMouseMove: function(event) {     
      this.translateX = event.offsetX
    }
}
```

Now is this variable available in you template and it is reactive. Every time you mouseover `div.synonym-list-wrapper` element, it would trigger method and update transformX value.

**Note:**
add `.self` to `@mousemove`:

```
@mousemove.self="onMouseMove($event)"
```

**It will only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself (not from a child element)**

Here is working example:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9c74gdu/5/)

Comment: But the problem is that u cant avoid that event is always triggered on its child elements but not itself, so thats the reason why I want a "proxy".

Comment: My point is that I wanna get the offsetX from the "currentTarget" when mouse moving over its child elements.

Comment: @胡亚雄 Manually calculating the offset from the parent with `e.offsetX` and the target child's index?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 no...for instance,we have structure like this "div.wrapper > div.parent > div > div > a", when mouseover the "a", how shall I calculate the offsetX on "div.parent".

Comment: @胡亚雄 Try providing a jsfiddle with all the styles you intend, with some example carousel pictures, so people can get a better idea of what you are trying to achieve. Maybe ask again with them to get some fresh attention。。。

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰  Look at the jsFiddle provided by t_dom93, If the mouse isnt on the text, when the mouse is moving meanwhile the text is moving, right? But all I want is that when I put my mouse on the text, it still has the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) may be what you want:

> It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: My point is that I wanna get the offsetX from the "currentTarget" when mouse moving over its child elements.